# how to write grammar for a non-regular syntax with ANTLR4

Tags: antlr

I'm using ANTLR4 to parse/analysis a script.
But the problem is the language of the script is non-regular.
For example:
It can declare variables name with any character such as double quote("), quote ('), comma (,), parentheses...
But when using, the variables are not enclosed by any sign, so it causes trouble for me to writing the grammar to parse.

Sample code:
**the first var (first column)** and **the second var, for next column** are String variables and the script will check **the first var (first column)**, if the first var is "ABC", it returns the first var, otherwise it returns the result of concating the two variables

```
String the first var (first column)

String the second var, for next column

IF (the first var (first column)=="ABC") THEN (the first var (first column)) ELSE (CONCAT(the first var (first column),  the second var, for next column))
```

Anyone can suggest me a grammar for this problem or it is supported by ANTLR4?
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you could use Antlr to parse this. One way is to represent the variable as a non-terminal. When you go to interpret this, you will need to concatenate the tokens prior to look-up in your symbol table. I do something like this for parsing ISO14977 grammars, which are terrible for this and other reasons. Alternatively, you could derive a new grammar from your declared symbols, using two passes.

Comment: @BartKiers the variables are **the first var (first column)** and **the second var, for next column**, I consciously set their name like that because in the act user can input the variable name freely, so the can include special character such as space, parentheses, comma...

Comment: I recommend not allowing such variables: not only is it a nightmare to parse, it is also pretty unreadable.

Comment: I know, but we don’t have permission to change the syntax. The data is already output by other system and we have to read/parse the content

Comment: No one believes me. This requires a multipass recognizer, and "scannerless" lexer. I do exactly this for ISO14977 where symbols can contain spaces. Please read the spec and my [implementation](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrVSIX/blob/master/LanguageServer/Iso14977Parser.g4) to understand. In the first pass, you will need to extract string variables. In the second pass, you can use a "scannerless" recognizer or construct a token stream using your string variables and additional grammatical structure of your language, which you don't define, but must be provided.

Comment: @kaby76 oh, sorry for lacked your comment, I will check it, thanks you

Comment: @kaby76 Your idea sounds interesting. Do you have a formal description of the parsing process? Your comment and the grammar code doesn't make it clear to me.

Comment: I have no idea if there's a term to describe this multi-pass language. The ISO14977 folks defined the language this way. The whole time I wrote this I'm just thinking about how bad this is, and why anyone would define a language this way. The implementation is similar to how macro processing is done for C with Antlr--use the results of the previous pass to construct a new token stream.

Comment: @kaby76 the action code you use in the g4 file is for C#?

Comment: @DaiVu Correct. The actions are C# code, and specifically for the NET Standard runtime, not Harwell's Antlr4cs runtime. The actions come directly from the ISO14977 spec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is solvable, mostly because you need a separator between individual tokens, which is (usually, in plain text processing) the space char. Hence you cannot use a space as part of a token, unless that token is delimited by some special character (usually quote chars, or comment introducer/end indicator).

In you case you cannot really tell when a variable would begin and when it would end, because you don't have such delimiters. Maybe you can consider a solution which MySQL has: include var names with any character in back ticks, like so:

```
String `the first var` (`first column`)

String `the second var`, for `next column`

IF (`the first var` (`first column`)=="ABC") THEN (`the first var` (`first column`)) ELSE (CONCAT(`the first var` (`first column`),  `the second var`, for `next column`))
```

to avoid having to use single/double quotes, which usually refer to string literals.

Comment: As I answer the above comment: I know, but we don’t have permission to change the syntax. The data is already output by other system and we have to read/parse the content